# LWP POST request not working

Tags: perl, post, lwp

The `if` statement is showing me that there is a response, but when I try to `print` the response I get nothing

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Request::Common;

# use this {"process": "mobileGps","phone": "9565551236"}

my $url  = "the url goes here";
my $json = '{data :{"process" : "mobileGps", "phone" : "9565551236"}}';

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( POST => $url );

$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$req->content( $json );

my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->request( $req );

if ( $res->is_success ) {
    print "It worked";
    print $res->decoded_content;
}
else {
    print $res->code;
}
```

I do have the URL: I just took it out for the purpose of this example.

What am I missing?

Comment: Rather than 'something went wrong' maybe check the status code with `$res -> code`?

Comment: @Sobrique the response is actually successful but I will change it to reflect on that (which is a great idea by the way) thanks!! any further suggestions?

Comment: Well, if the response is successful, then that means you need to figure out what's happening on the remote server. e.g. check the logs on the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try debugging your script like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP::ConsoleLogger::Easy qw( debug_ua );
use LWP::UserAgent;

# use this {"process": "mobileGps","phone": "9565551236"}

my $url = "the url goes here";
my $json = '{data :{"process" : "mobileGps", "phone" : "9565551236"}}';

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url);

$req->header('Content-Type' =>'application/json');
$req->content($json);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
debug_ua( $ua );
my $res = $ua->request($req);


if ($res->is_success) {
    print "It worked";
    print $res->decoded_content;
} else {
    print $res->code;
}
```

That will (hopefully) give you a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the debugger, or add some print statements to see how your program is progressing?

If not then this is going to be another case of on-line turn-by-turn debugging, which benefits no one except the OP, and the ultimate diagnosis is that they should have learned the language first

The internet can be wise, but it will make many more *artisans Pretender* than craftsmen

Please don't ever expect to make a half-hearted attempt at a sketch, and then rope in the rest of the world to finish your job. It takes a *huge* amount of experience, aptitude, and understanding to get even a `"What's your name" .. "Hello"` program working, and things only get harder thereafter

If you don't like being careful and thorough, and would rather ask for people to do your stuff for you than discover a solution by experimentation, then you are a manager, not a programmer. I hope you will never try to advance a software career by getting great at delegating, because that doesn't work with software

Here. Use this as you will. The world is full of managers; it is good programmers that we need

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use constant URL => 'http://example.com/';

use LWP;

my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $json = '{}';

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( POST => URL );
$req->header( content_type => 'application/json' );
$req->content( $json );

my $res = $ua->request( $req );

say $res->as_string;
```

Comment: You know, I was just trying to finish something that I am doing just to pass time learning perl, I thought of it much like asking a coworker for pointers. People ask way worse questions in hackatons, but I can only imagine if the normal response would be "you can't figure it out yourself?" normally people ask for other people for help. It was a simple question really, and I didn't even use your code.

Comment: @Alex_adl04: If you are trying to learn Perl then there is much more reason why you should at least attempt the debugging process yourself. You will learn nothing by being handed a debugged solution. I don't see how hackathons are in any way relevant, but I can only imagine if the usual approach were "please fix this for me". We would end up with a world of people who knew only how to get other people to do their stuff for them. I don't care a jot whether or not you used my code. The vast majority of people who use these answers came here searching for help with a similar problem.

Comment: @Alex_adl04: Notice that even your accepted answer says *"Try debugging your script"*. No one should need to be told that. You also have a downvote on your question, so someone else agrees with me.

Answer (score -1):

The code is fine. The problem must be with the server that is serving the request upon status code 200. You should check at server's end.